# at command Option Code

Tags: default-programs

I was reading from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands) and it has the `at` package listed as mandatory, and it wasn't present on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Is this a Wikipedia typo or should I check that the iso file I installed from is valid?

Comment: That page simply lists the commands that (emphasis mine) "***can** be found on Unix operating systems and most Unix-like operating systems*. That doesn't mean they absolutely _must_ be installed by default. Simply that they are commonly available on *nix systems.

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, I'm sure. Not about the IEEE, but about the English used by wikipedia. _Can be found_ isn't the same as _must be found_. In any case, if you look at the linked page, you'll see that only a few of them (including `at`, admittedly) are listed as mandatory. So it seems pretty clear. And [even the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) only requires that a conforming system _support_ these utilities, not that it ships with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix is NOT Linux.

"at" is optional on Linux machines.

Comment: I find this new information very unsettling

Comment: @Adam Why? You can simply install it!

Comment: yeah no it's more embarrassing in that it's obvious that my comprehension of Linux as a type of Unix is clearly false

Comment: ah that :D @Adam well Linux is a (bastard?) child of Unix that's grown up now  :D